# What thing facebook use to load page in components/parts

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-deployment

What is the best way to load our html page graduatily in parts or components that's reduce the load of website and also useful for show bulk of data like facebook pages,Any easy way to do that's and I know html css js django with that's have any way to do that's type of work or I need to learn any other thing to do that's Thank you .

Comment: Look into JavaScript bundlers like webpack, and component libraries like React

Comment: If able to do with react then how to do with that in components body loads once all of them.